# When Converting PDFs, Newlines Become Paragraphs

Tags: pdf, conversion, calibre

I'm attempting to use Calibre to convert a book-length PDF to a .mobi format for reading on my Kindle.  When I do this, however, every line from the original ends up as being a standalone paragraph in this sort of way:

```
Hume, the conversation mercifully shifted to Wall Street.  We marveled at the

systematic errors in decision making that CEOs and business leaders make
```

Is there a setting that would make it convert more gracefully?